# Custom Function Filter ordering on YADCF

Tags: yadcf

First of all, thank you so much for your support of YADCF. It's a fantastic tool! Second, I'm not a programmer (I know enough to break stuff :D) so I apologize in advance for having to bother you at all. It's possible my question has even already been answered, I just don't know what to search for.

I'm using the YADCF 0.8.8 table on DOM Source (small "d"). I've built a custom_func_filter based on 11 values & labels. The weird thing is, when the drop-down menu displays for the filter, the labels are not in the order they're defined in.

In trying to figure out what the issue was, I changed the values and labels to numbers from 01 - 11 instead of text to see how it was moving things around. Apparently it's anything over 10 items that it begins to jumble everything up. Here's a side-by-side comparison on what it looks like:

[custom_func_filter comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K9uY.jpg)

I'm behind a firewall so it's not easy to share my code, but I'll figure out a way to if need be. I just wasn't sure if there was something I was missing.

Using datatables 1.9.4, jquery 1.11.3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome :)

Quick answer: Use the [sort_as: "none"](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/9ea72417dc805efa4ca667335c68c98839462f3f/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L141) and make sure the `data` array is in your desired order

Explanation: BEcause in custom function filtering the select is being populated by (`data`) array of objects `value`/`label` the sort as (as its implemented now) wont really sort the `data`, so since you populate `data` manually, *just make sure its in your desired order*